# Correct way to initialize class property with method

Tags: swift, class, properties, class-method

I'm doing a small game in Swift and I got stuck on initializing property with a class method.

```
 class Game {
 var height: Int
 var width: Int
 var board: [[String]] = createBoard()


 init(height: Int, width: Int) {
    self.height = height
    self.width = width
 }

 func createBoard() -> [[String]]{
   var gameBoard: [[String]] = []
    //working with width and height props from above
    //filling the board and returning
   return gameBoard
  }
 }
```

how can I set board value as a result of function **createBoard()**? (inside create board I'm working with height and width)

Comment: width and height are var in your example – you may wanna change those to let – but if you really intend to change the board size at runtime add a didSet {} handler and invalidate / recreate your gameBoard there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @vadian told lazy is a good way of doing it. But I want to add something.

I think you need to make your `height` and `width` private, to prevent changing them from outside, lazy block will be called once and if you will change for ex. `height` from 10 to 100 you board calculation will not be called. If you need to change your game settings after initializing it so I will suggest another option to do it.

```
    class Game {
        var height: Int {
            didSet {
                board = self.updateGameBoard(height: height,
                                             width: width)
            }
        }
        var width: Int {
            didSet {
                board = self.updateGameBoard(height: height,
                                             width: width)
            } 
        }
    
        lazy var board: [[String]] = {
            return updateGameBoard(height: height, width: width)
        }()
    
        init(height: Int, width: Int) {
           self.height = height
           self.width = width
        }

        private func updateGameBoard(height: Int, 
                                     width: Int) -> [[String]] {
            var gameBoard: [[String]] = []
            //working with width and height props from above
            //filling the board and returning
            return gameBoard
        }
   }
```

This will allow you to change update the board reactive from outside by changing `height` or `width`

Answer (score 1):

Create the property *lazily*.

The benefit is the closure is not executed until the property is read the first time

```
class Game {
    var height: Int
    var width: Int
    lazy var board: [[String]] = {
        var gameBoard: [[String]] = []
        //working with width and height props from above
        //filling the board and returning
        return gameBoard
    }()


    init(height: Int, width: Int) {
       self.height = height
       self.width = width
    }
 }
```